# Call helper method from cms template

Tags: template, cms, helper

Is it possible to call a helper method to output a variable in a cms template?

Similar in fashion to the way helpers can be called in layout files such as:

```
<node helper="myhelper/myhelpermethod" />
```

Maybe there is some way to do like:

```
{{module method="params"}}
```

which is similar to

```
{{store direct_url="about-magento-demo-store"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a template (.phtml ) file and call your helper function there.

   `Mage::helper('myhelper')->myHelperMethod();`
2. Then inside the CMS page call the template file

   `{{block type="core/template" template="path/to/file/mytemplate.phtml"}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can create template where you can call helper. And then insert a block with this template.

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/variable.phtml"}}
```